# how to add a checkbox in Master Details view in Devexpress

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I am implementing master detail view in devexpress grid control in winforms using C#.

In MasterRowGetChildList event I am binding data at runtime on expansion of grid using e.childlist property.

how to add a checkbox in dynamic data grid.

Comment: you want to use the check-box to select rows? if yes what version of devexpress are you using?

Comment: Why do you not add an unbound column??

Comment: Thanks Ezi,Niranjan. I found the solution I simply added    this.gridname.OptionsSelection.MultiSelectMode = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridMultiSelectMode.CheckBoxRowSelect; and
            this.grdname.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true;

Comment: please add this as a answer. and select it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.gridname.OptionsSelection.MultiSelectMode = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridMultiSelectMode.CheckBoxRowSelect;

this.grdname.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true;
```